# Jquery Autocomplete with multiple selections on combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I have some existing jquery autocomplete code which has all of the functionality that I need. The autocomplete searches combobox for matches that start with first character. All I need to do is add multiple selection functionality as such:

jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="PalmComputingPlatform" content="True">
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>WebFOCUS Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>
Please choose an option :
<select size="3" id="decision2">
<option selected>1521</option>
<option>3336</option>
<option>5454</option>
<option>7890</option>
<option>2178</option>
</select>
</div>

<style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            classes: {
              "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
            }
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .on( "mousedown", function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .on( "click", function() {
            input.trigger( "focus" );
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
 
    $( "#decision2" ).combobox();
    $( "#decision2" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#decision2" ).toggle();
    });
  } );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Provide your code, we don't have enough time to search it on github. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code. Please check and let me know if that's what you wanted.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="PalmComputingPlatform" content="True">
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>WebFOCUS Report</title>
</head>

<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        Please choose an option :
        <select size="3" id="decision2">
      <option selected>1521</option>
      <option>3336</option>
      <option>5454</option>
      <option>7890</option>
      <option>2178</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <style>
        .custom-combobox {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .custom-combobox-toggle {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-left: -1px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .custom-combobox-input {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.widget("custom.combobox", {
                _create: function() {
                    this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                        .addClass("custom-combobox")
                        .insertAfter(this.element);

                    this.element.hide();
                    this._createAutocomplete();
                    this._createShowAllButton();
                },

                _createAutocomplete: function() {
                    var sourceArray = [];
                    var selectItems = this.element.context.children;
                    $.each(selectItems, function(i, item) {
                        sourceArray.push(item.value);
                    });

                    var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
                        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

                    function split(val) {
                        return val.split(/,\s*/);
                    }

                    function extractLast(term) {
                        return split(term).pop();
                    }

                    this.input = $("<input>")
                        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                        .val(value)
                        .attr("title", "")
                        .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
                        .autocomplete({
                            delay: 0,
                            minLength: 0,
                            source: function(request, response) {
                                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                                var term = extractLast(request.term),
                                    matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
                                response($.grep(sourceArray, function(item) {
                                    return matcher.test(item);
                                }));
                            },
                            select: function(event, ui) {
                                var terms = split(this.value);
                                // remove the current input
                                terms.pop();
                                // add the selected item
                                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                                terms.push("");
                                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .tooltip({
                            classes: {
                                "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
                            }
                        });
                },

                _createShowAllButton: function() {
                    var input = this.input,
                        wasOpen = false;

                    $("<a>")
                        .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                        .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                        .tooltip()
                        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                        .button({
                            icons: {
                                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                            },
                            text: false
                        })
                        .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                        .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
                        .on("mousedown", function() {
                            wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
                        })
                        .on("click", function() {
                            input.trigger("focus");

                            // Close if already visible
                            if (wasOpen) {
                                return;
                            }

                            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                            input.autocomplete("search", "");
                        });
                },

                _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {

                    // Selected an item, nothing to do
                    if (ui.item) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                    var value = this.input.val(),
                        valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                        valid = false;
                    this.element.children("option").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    // Found a match, nothing to do
                    if (valid) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Remove invalid value
                    this.input
                        .val("")
                        .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
                        .tooltip("open");
                    this.element.val("");
                    this._delay(function() {
                        this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                    }, 2500);
                    this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
                },

                _destroy: function() {
                    this.wrapper.remove();
                    this.element.show();
                }
            });

            $("#decision2").combobox();
            $("#decision2").on("click", function() {
                $("#decision2").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Aminur. Is there a way to change this so that the suggestions only show what starts with the first input character as opposed to contains? For example if I type '2' i would only like to see '2178' as opposed to '2178' and '1521'

Comment: Edited my answer, it's now working as the new requirement. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try the link https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple.html, which has the correct solution your question.

Comment: This has correct functionality the only problem with implementing this is that the source in the example you gave comes from an array and in my code it comes from an html listbox.